# Javascript nested object filtering create new object

Tags: javascript, json, filter, javascript-objects

Suppose I have object

```
let x = { "people" :{
             "Sally": "value",
             "Bob" : "other value"
                    },
          "cars" :{
             "Saab" : "this",
             "Chevy": "that"
                    },
           "trees":{
              "Birch" : "what",
              "Oak" : "where"
                    }
                }
```

I want to search, so if I searched for "S" I'd get back an array that was

```
{ "people" :{
     "Sally": "value",
          },
  "cars" :{
     "Saab" : "this",
          }
}
```

And if I searched for "b" I'd get:

```
{ "people" :{
        "Bob" : "other value"
           },
   "trees":{
        "Birch" : "what",
           }
}
```

or "bo" would return

```
    { "people" :{
        "Bob" : "other value"
     }
```

And if I searched "e" I'd get

```
{  "cars" :{
             "Chevy": "that"
            }
}
```

Note that the "people" and "trees" isn't caught by the search for 'e'.

The strut will be of a fixed depth, and we only ever want to catch *keys* that match the filter and don't have children (we're also not interested in values that match, just keys).

Adding npm dependencies is acceptable.

Attempted solution:

```
    filteredList(unfiltered,searchVal) {
  return unfiltered.filter(search=> {
    return search.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())
  })
}
```

Obviously there's more to it, but I'm not sure which direction to proceed.

Comment: updated per request

Comment: If the structure can be arbitrarily deep, you'll need to use recursion.

Comment: Just FYI, `filter` is an method of arrays. You have an object.

Comment: I could remove the "arbitrary depth" constraint. I was trying to think future-proof, but right now my data is consistently 5 levels deep. I will update the question, thank you @Amy.

Comment: I took that out, but, e.g. here's the head of the actual data:
     "Configs": {
        "Head Configs": {
            "Configuration": {
                "hdCfgWidth": {
                    "Name": "Head Width",
                    "Value": 3,
    ....
Your solution will work, I just need to build it out to the right depth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic attempt. It's seems work quite fine but I'm very sure that it may be possible to make even better. But I don't know how.

```js
let x = {
  "people": {
    "Sally": "value",
    "Bob": "other value"
  },
  "cars": {
    "Saab": "this",
    "Chevy": "that"
  },
  "trees": {
    "Birch": "what",
    "Oak": "where"
  }
}

let search = "B";

let result = {};

for (let key in x) {
  let tmp = {};
  for (let subKey in x[key]) {
    if (subKey.includes(search)) { // Use startsWithif you want even substring that aren't at the beginning
      tmp[subKey] = x[key][subKey];
    }
    if (Object.keys(tmp).length > 0) {
      result[key] = Object.assign({}, tmp);
    }
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

If you want an arbitrary deep, you should try with some kind of recursion, but that will be more complex.

Comment: No need for a JSFiddle when you can use a stack snippet.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks!!

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much, that works exactly the way I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses the lodash library. Lodash has a number of super useful methods for object manipulation, in this case `_.pickBy` and `_.mapValues` can be used to filter your nested object.

Example:

```js
let x = {
  "people": {
    "Sally": "value",
    "Bob": "other value"
  },
  "cars": {
    "Saab": "this",
    "Chevy": "that"
  },
  "trees": {
    "Birch": "what",
    "Oak": "where"
  }
}

function search(query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    const matched = _.mapValues(x, v => _.pickBy(v, (_, k) => k.toLowerCase().includes(query)));
    return _.pickBy(matched, v => Object.keys(v).length)
}

console.log(search("S"))
console.log(search("b"))
console.log(search("bo"))
console.log(search("e"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Disclaimer, the solution for `"b"` includes one additional result (`"Saab"`) than your example, not sure if you meant to leave it out.

Comment: lol no, you're right, my "filter by eye" method missed that. This is a really neat solution! Thanks!

Comment: Use `startsWith` instead of `includes`.

Comment: @EnderLook Wouldn't that break OPs `"e"` case, which should return `"Chevy"` even though the match is not at the start?

Comment: @CRice, ohh, I haven't noticed that. I'm very sorry.